# Split a logfile

Tags: powershell

I have a log file with this:

```
Wed Oct 17 05:39:27 2018 : Resource = 'test04' cstep= 'titi04' time =18.751s 
Wed Oct 17 05:40:31 2018 : Resource = 'test05' cstep= 'titi05' time =58.407s 
Wed Oct 17 05:41:31 2018 : Resource = 'test06' cstep= 'titi06' time =3.400s 
Wed Oct 17 05:42:31 2018 : Resource = 'test07' cstep= 'titi07' time =4.402s
```

I want split and want only the values greater than 5:

```
18.751
58.407
```

My script is in PowerShell and collects all values, not just values greater than 5:

```
$list = Get-Content "C:\Users\Desktop\slow_trans\log_file.txt"

$results = foreach ($line in $list) {
    $line.Split('=')[3].Trim().TrimEnd('s')
}

$results
```

Results are

```
18.751 
58.407 
3.400
4.402
```

I want only

```
3.400
4.402
```

Comment: First you say that you want only values greater than 5, then you say you want only values less than 5. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following casts the selected string as double and then returns only those which are less than 5

```
$results = Foreach ($line in $list) {
    $val = [double]$line.Split('=')[3].Trim().TrimEnd('s')
    if($val -lt 5) {
        $val
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, now i want convert Wed Oct 17 05:41:31 2018 to 2018-10-17 05:41:31, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Changing the requirements on the fly is normally a no go,
so you don't deserve it.
Also the wording `Superior 5` reminds me at a previous question from another user account..

Nevertheless here a script with a single pipe and datetime conversion.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\06\SO_53170145.ps1
Get-Content .\logfile.txt |
  Where-Object {$_ -match '^(.*?) : .*time =([0-9\.]+)s'}|
    Select-Object @{n='DT';e={([datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1],'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))}},
                  @{n='val';e={[double]$Matches[2]}} |
      Where-Object val -le 5
```

Sample output (decimal comma due to my German locale)

```
DT                    val
--                    ---
2018-10-17 05:41:31   3,4
2018-10-17 05:42:31 4,402
```

Comment: my new code is :

$list = Get-Content "C:\Users\\Desktop\log.txt"
$Results = Foreach ($line in $list) {

    $val = [double]$line.Split('=')[3].Trim().TrimEnd('s')
    if($val -lt 5) {
        
        #$line.Split(' ')[3]
        $line    
    }
}
$Results

 i want convert Wed Oct 17 05:41:31 2018 to 2018-10-17 05:41:31 easily

Answer (score 0):

`Select-String` is one option:

```
(Select-String -Path "TargetLog.txt" -Pattern ".*(?<time>\d+\.\d+)s").Matches |
    ForEach-Object {
        if([double]$_.Groups['time'].Value -lt 5.0) {$_.Value}
    }
```

This will output the entire matching line:

```
Wed Oct 17 05:41:31 2018 : Resource = 'test06' cstep= 'titi06' time =3.400s
Wed Oct 17 05:42:31 2018 : Resource = 'test07' cstep= 'titi07' time =4.402s
```

If you only want the number from each line, change the `if` block to this:

`{$_.Groups['time'].Value}`

Comment: this is not what i want, i want extract the value Wed Oct 17 05:41:31 2018 and  convert to  2018-10-17 05:41:31 easily